# Getting around generic type covariance lack of function input

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I am trying to make use of covariant types in order to make generics useful.

I have a generic interface foo that I want to be able to both get and set a property of type T. When declaring the object I don't know what implementing instance I'll be given and so covariance allows for the following declaration

```
 Foo<ibasetype> genericFoo = new implementationOfFoo();
```

Where implementationOfFoo is

```
 Class implementationOfFoo : Foo<baseTypeA>{}
```

This works for declaration but it doesn't allow the interface to require an instance of the type baseTypeA as a parameter because covariance only allows returning an instance of the type.

I'm unable to make the interface type invariant as is suggested in other posts because that requires I specifically declare the appropriate class type during object declaration which is not possible as I don't know what instance of implementing class I'll be given.

I am also unable to declare a second type and make that type contravariant as that also triggers a compiler error similar to the invariant case during declaration.

The code that uses this class will handle the appropriate object generation based on reflection prior to passing the object to the implementations various functions so there's no concern of any rule breaking and any exceptions that occur will simply be cleaned up as part of the process of building the code that makes use of the interface.

I assume there's some trick with covariance to get around this shortcoming but I haven't found any guides which discuss this concern. How do I get around this?

Per the responses to my initial question, I would like to be able to build an interface with types of various interfaces I define as the requirements of the main generic interface types. For example

```
 Public interface Foo<typeA> where typeA:iModelA{
      typeA prop1{get;set;}
      Void doSomething (typeA sameAsProp1)
 }
```

The implementation of the interface must be providing a type which implements iModelA so I simply need to use reflection to determine what the type is and then in my case I use the url provided to construct an instance of that type and pass it to the interface instances ModelA parameter. Then when I need the object I just call the ModelA getter and get from the implementation the iModelA it seems appropriate to provide in that instance.

In my code is declare
Foo fooInstance = getFooInstance(inputs)

For example the page I'm constructing has input fields which on a button click generates a new url which is redirected to. Those same url parameters are then reviewed on the subsequent page load to construct an instance of the base object (which is also based on parameters in the url). The setter logic then reloads the fields based on the passed instance of the iModelA objects parameters.

This logic will be the same regardless of the implementation of the interface so I know its a perfect candidate for an interface and the generic types allow me to impose structure across various objects within the implementation. This if two objects need to reference the exact same type, the generic requirements can manage those needs.

I know that I could get away with not doing a generic interface like so

```
 Interface nonGenericFoo{
      iModelA prop1{get;set;}
      Void doSomething (iModelA sameAsProp1)
 }
```

However, this means that across functions and properties within the main interface the implementation of the interfaces might be declared differently which will be problematic. In addition, the implementing class will need to make assumptions about the implemention instance which I want to avoid. I want all assumptions to be handled by the main code and let the interface implementations know exactly what they're working with.

Comment: It isn't clear how you are actually calling the methods of your interfaces. Can you expand your example for both input and output cases?

Comment: It's not possible to use covariance on parameters, nor contravariance on return types, because otherwise there would be a type mismatch "hole". If you show your full use case, maybe we can work around it. If the whole thing is done using reflection then perhaps you should use invariant instead, and use non-generic base classes

Comment: @Charlieface I added some examples of how I'd plan to instantiate and use the functions.

Comment: So I stand by what I said: variance is impossible here. If it were possible then a typing hole could open up: you could take a `Foo<Derived>` cast it to a `Foo<IBase>` then try to store an `IOtherDerived` in `prop1`. So this has to be prohibited, and the same applies in the reverse for getters. You say you are using reflection, perhaps you should carry on using reflection to create the objects? A partial workaround is to factor out a non-generic `FooBase` abstract class or interface, containing all non-generic functions. Then you only need reflection for the instantiation, ....

Comment: .... and you can cast it back to `FooBase`, meanwhile the object itself knows its own `T` type and doesn't need reflection or casting for its internal methods. The point is that often the external code that instantiates actually doesn't need to know the generic type later, it can just call `DoThings()` and the object will know internally what to do